# MySQL Query help with hit statistics?

Tags: php, mysql

```
TABLE: pages
pageId | name
 1     | Home
 2     | About Us
 3     | Contact Us
```

Then i have stats stored:

```
TABLE: hits
hid | created    | assignId
01  | 1000000001 | 1
02  | 1000000002 | 1
03  | 1000000003 | 3
```

So basically, "Home" was opened twice, "About us" never, and "Contact us" once. Also notice that Contact us was most recently accessed.

I need a query that returns this:

```
pageId | name         | lastAccessDate
 1     | Home         | 1000000002   --> NB: Notice that it takes the higher one
 2     | About Us     | null
 3     | Contact Us   | 1000000003
```

Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: `ORDER BY created DESC GROUP BY assignId`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
SELECT p.pageId, p.name, MAX(s.created) FROM pages p LEFT JOIN stats s ON p.pageId=s.assignId GROUP BY p.pageId ORDER BY pageid ASC
```